# Using optparse to read in a list from command line options

Tags: python, parsing, eval

I am calling a python script with the following command line:

```
myscript.py --myopt="[(5.,5.),(-5.,-5.)]"
```

The question is -- how to convert myopt to a list variable.  My solution was to use optparse, treating myopt as a string, and using

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()    
myopt = eval(options.myopt)
```

Now, because I used `eval()` I feel a bit like Dobby the house elf, having knowingly transgressed the commandments of great (coding) wizards, and wanting to self-flagellate myself in punishment.

But are there better options for parsing lists or tuples or lists of tuples from the command line?..  I've seen solutions that use `split()`, but this won't work here since this isn't a simple list.  Keep in mind, also, that this is being done in the context of mostly one-off scientific computing with no security concerns -- so perhaps `eval()` isn't as evil here?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ast.literal_eval(node_or_string):](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast-helpers)

> Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a string containing a Python
>   expression. The string or node
>   provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures:
>   strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating
>   strings containing Python expressions
>   from untrusted sources without the
>   need to parse the values oneself.

So you can do

```
import ast
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()    
myopt = ast.literal_eval(options.myopt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json) instead. The syntax is not exactly `Python`, but close enough.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("[[5.0,5.0],[-5.0,-5.0]]")
[[5.0, 5.0], [-5.0, -5.0]]
>>> [tuple(p) for p in json.loads("[[5.0,5.0],[-5.0,-5.0]]")]
[(5.0, 5.0), (-5.0, -5.0)]
>>>
```